# Yii 2 - how to disable GridView column header?

Tags: yii2

I'm attempting to disable Yii2 GridView DataColumn's header - in Yii 1.1 it was done via setting the header property to false. However this does not apply for Yii 2

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'some_column',
            'header' => false,
        ],
    ]
]);
```

I could do it by redefining header closure that returns empty string but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 12):

You can completely disable `GridView` column header by adding `showHeader` configuration:

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'showHeader'=> false,
    // ...
]);
```

Reference: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview#$showHeader-detail

Answer (score 3):

And to answer my own question, in Yii2 the proper property is `label` not `header`:

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'some_column',
            'label' => false,
        ],
    ]
]);
```